# Salesforce API: get the time on the Salesforce server

Tags: time, salesforce

With the Salesforce API, is there a way to get the current time on the Salesforce server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `getServerTimestamp()` method:

In C#:

```cs
// binding is of type SforceService 
GetServerTimestampResult timestamp = binding.getServerTimestamp();
```

In Java:

```java
// connection is of type EnterpriseConnection 
GetServerTimestampResult timestamp = connection.getServerTimestamp();
```

See [Salesforce API Docs: getServerTimestamp()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getservertimestamp.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This method can be used to get time on server

```
GetServerTimestampResult timestamp = connection.getServerTimestamp();
```

Refrence - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_getservertimestamp.htm